# Regex: Get text between two characters

Tags: regex

String: `Y|ZXIET|V| |N|100|Y||ZXIET|ZXIET|Nl`
Need to get first `ZXIET`.

I've tried this `(?<=Y\|)(.*)(?=\|)`. It gets it right for the first `Y\|`, but it takes the last `|` character, instead of the first one.

Comment: If the string were `Y|ZXIET` would you want `ZXIET` returned or a conclusion that there is no match?

Comment: None of the answers in the answer marked as duplicate matches the accepted answer here, why closing as duplicate?

Comment: @Andronicus, I agree, so am voting to reopen. The cited earlier question suggests the answer is merely to change a match from greedy to non-greedy. That was my initial impression, but as I explained in my answer, that is not sufficient.

Comment: md123, kindly answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you provided even simple `([A-Z])\w+` does the job.

What you're looking for is `(?<=Y\|)([^|]*)`. It matches every character but `|` in the second group.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're right, thank you for that comment!

Comment: I may or may not be right. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps easiest to just match the regular expression

```
(?<=Y\|)[^|]*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ7ZHl/1/)

and take the first match. This matches `ZXIET` after `"Y|"` and an empty string after the second `"Y|"`.

Alternatively, suppose you simply added a question mark to `(.*)` in the regex your tried, to make it non-greedy, causing it to stop immediately before the first, rather than last, `"|"`:

```
(?<=Y\|)(.*?)(?=\|)
```

Moreover, there really is no point in having a capture group, as it will simply return the match, which you get anyway:

```
(?<=Y\|).*?(?=\|)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ7ZHl/1/)

With the example that matches `ZXIETV` and `|ZXIET`. However, if the example string were

```
Y||ZXIETV| |N|100|Y||ZXIET|ZXIET|Nl
```

the first match would be `|ZXIETV` which is probably not what you want. I therefore suggest you use the first regex I suggested.

Comment: After posting I noticed that the regex I suggested is very similar to the one @Andronicus gave earlier. I will leave my answer for the discussion about modifying the OP's regex.